# changing fill_value for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How can I change the fill value of a masked numpy array from 65536.0 to -9999.0

arr

```
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 65536.0)
```

I tried numpy.ma.fill_value, but it is not working

Comment: Look also at `ma.filled`.  You can use different fills depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the property directly or use [`np.ma.set_fill_value`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ma.set_fill_value.html#numpy.ma.set_fill_value):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ma.array([1,2,3])
print(a.fill_value) # 999999

a.fill_value = -100
print(a.fill_value) # -100

np.ma.set_fill_value(a, -999)
print(a.fill_value) # -999
```

Depending on your `dtype` (if it is `np.uint`) negative values result in a `ValueError`.

If that does not work, please give some more information about the numpy/python version and the dtype of your array.